# How to enable dragging of the scroll handle in a ScrollViewer contained in the template of a CalendarDayButton

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the following example, the scroll bars of the ListBox within the control template of the CalendarDayButton will not scroll by dragging the scroll handle.  However, clicking in the scroll bar works fine.  My best guess is something in either the Calendar or CalendarDayButton is doing something to the mouse events outside of my understanding.

Is it possible to restore the drag-n-scroll behavior of the ScrollViewer?

```
<Window 
x:Class="CustomCalendar.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
Title="MainWindow" 
Width="500"
Height="400"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid MaxHeight="220">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="NormalText" TextElement.FontSize="14" TextElement.Foreground="#FF333333" Margin="1,0,1,0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Milk"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Milk"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Milk"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListBoxItem>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Calendar CalendarDayButtonStyle="{DynamicResource CalendarDayButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

It's looking like the CalendarItem may be the culprit here. When it adds the CalendarDayButton it's setting some event handlers, specifically the MouseLeftButtonDownEvent.  In that handler it is capturing the mouse which it seems to be taking the capture away from the Scroll handle.  Looking in how to overcome that as my next course of action.

Comment: Upon further digging, setting a day as a BlackoutDate prevents the mouse down event handler assigned from the CalendarItem to the CalendarDayButton from capturing the mouse. Not ideal, but a workaround. Subclassing CalendarItem to change this behavior might be next.

Comment: Never mind subclassing CalendarItem, it's a sealed class.